Regarding numbering of subfigure on the top left
I have included the following latex code in my paper which gives the numbering of the subfigure at the bottom center.
\begin{figure}[ht!]%\vspace*{3.0ex}
  \centering
  \subfigure[]
  {\includegraphics*[width=0.46\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{After modify review_images/A.png}\label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray}}
  \hspace{2mm}\centering\subfigure[]
  {\includegraphics*[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{After modify review_images/B.png}\label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray b}}
 \vspace{-1ex}\caption{(a) Map of the world. (b) X-ray image of the Map.}\vspace*{0.0ex}
 \end{figure}

However, I want the subfigure to be numbered at the top left. Can anyone alter my code so that this happens? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome! Looking at your code, it seems you’re using the obsolete package subfigure. Can you please turn your snippet into a full document?

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717428/subfigure-customization

I suggest you stop using the deprecated subfigure package, which was last updated in 2002, and start using the much more recent, and still actively maintained, subcaption package.
I take it that you want to place both the overall caption and the subfigure-related (sub)captions flush-left.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\begin{subfigure}{0.46\textwidth}
  \caption{Map of the world}
  \label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray a}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio=true]{After modify review_images/A.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
  \caption{X-ray image of the map}
  \label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray b}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{After modify review_images/B.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to figures \ref{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray a} and \ref{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray b}.
\end{document}


Don't use subfigure: it's obsolete and its author provided the replacement package subfig several years ago.
Use the features in subfig in order to modify the layout.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{
  position=top,
  singlelinecheck=false,
}
\MakeRobust{\subref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\subfloat[\label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray b}]{%
  \includegraphics*[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
}
\caption{%
  \subref{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray} Map of the world.
  \subref{fig:SEM of sample and 4D xray b} X-ray image of the Map.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


Why using subfig over subcaption? No particular reason: the latter package is more powerful, actually. However, some document classes (for instance revtex4-2 and others) don't like caption and therefore loading subcaption is out of question. On the other hand, subfig provides the option caption=false that won't load caption and so it's usually compatible with those document classes.
About your code: calling \includegraphics* isn't necessary unless you want to clip parts of the image with trim or viewport. And in this case it's possible (and in my opinion better) to use the clip option instead of *. Also keepaspectratio isn't needed in your code, because you only specify the width; the =true part can be omitted.
